# WITH(nolock) in every SELECT - NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to find a way to use with(nolock) in every SELECT I do in NHibernate.
Doesn't matter if it's being called with hql, Linq Queries or criteria, as long as when SELECT is performed, with(nolock) comes along!

Comment: I am just curious as to why you would want to do this for all queries?  I can see certain functions that don't require the latest data - but all functions?  This is a very dangerous design which can lead to erroneous data in your database.  I would be very cautious of using this in any production code.

Comment: Yes, it'sextremely dangerous. However, some bad-designed legacy systems has so many long-running trans that they use WITH(NOLOCK) everywhere. If something goes wrong because of this low isolation level, don't blame on us!! We warned you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set yout database Transaction Isolation level to `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`

NOLOCK is equivalenteto READUNCOMMITED, so you get the same effect if your connection uses that transaction isolation level.

WARNING! DANGER! READ THIS!!!

This is the best explanation I've ever found on NOLOCK HINT (and HINTS in general).
It's worth reading:

[SQL Server NOLOCK Hint & other poor ideas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx)

ADDED REFERENCES:

[SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

[Adjusting Transaction Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189542.aspx)

[Isolation Levels (OLE DB)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131673.aspx)

Comment: I saw in another post that it doesn't make my select with(nolock)'d. Are you sure about that ?

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari running an uncommitted isolation level is the SAME as making your query no-lock.

Comment: Actually, I have one more question. If I do this, `ITransaction trans = session.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)` will I have the same result ? Thanks

Comment: Ye, you will. There are severeal places where you can do that. Transaction is one of them. Other is calling the SET command after opening the connection. I haven't worked with NHibernate, so I don't know whichis the easiest way to "inject" this code. Please, be aware that this isolation level is weak, and you can do something wrong if you rely on the results of a query to take some decision, because you can be reading changes that can be rolled back by other transactions later. Read uncommitted is exactly that: access data onm a transaction which hasn't been commited yet.

Comment: But thats something odd happening (I guess). I have this query (hql) `session.CreateQuery("select p from Product as p"); trans.Commit()`, where my ITransaction = `ITransaction trans = session.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);`. But the sql output (auto_sql) is showed like that: `SELECT product0_.Id as Id0_0_, product0_.Name as Name0_0_, FROM Product product0_ WHERE product0_.Id = @p0`. My point is, I see no with(nolock) in this query. Is that supposed to happen ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's supposed to happen.

Comment: The "NOLOCK" or "READUNCOMMITED" behaviour can be set, at the connection level, with `SET ISOLATION LEVEL`, at the transaction level, just like you're doing it, or at the table level, with `WITH(NOLOCK)` query hint. Proof of concept: open SSMS, in new qry window: `BEGIN TRAN`, modify product table, **don't commit**. Open a new qry window in SSMS, try to select from product: it will lock. Run your NHibernate qry: will run w/o locking. Check the 2nd qry is locked until you commit the 1st one. Do commit it, and get back to the 2nd qry and check the lock was released and the qry has run

Comment: @JotaBe So, your point is, the way I'm using is correct ? It has the with(nolock) ? Thanks !

Comment: And just one last doubt too, this ReadUncommited works only with SELECT right ? Never on update, delete or inserts right ? Thanks !

Comment: My point is that you should to the proof of concept to see it for yourself. And to read the docs, to understand what is this Isolation Level and why you can get into trouble if you use it all the time. This should be a last resort.

Comment: I understood what it does ! Thanks btw ! I just want to know if it only works with select. thanks